# Gzip a single field in json in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, gzip

Say I have a ruby Hash with a single property that is a very large string.  It's so large that compressing the string may make sense.  Compressing the string is trivial using `ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress`, but converting that hash to JSON is proving to be a problem due to encoding.

Basically, this code fails:

`{ compressed: ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress('asdf') }.to_json`

with the following error:

`JSON::GeneratorError: Invalid Unicode [8b 08 00 56 dd] at 1`

A hash that does not contain any compressed data gets encoded as UTF-8 when converted to json using `to_json`, but calling `ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress('asdf').encode('UTF-8')` just fails with the following error:

`Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x8B" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`

Is this a fool's errand I'm on?  Can my goal be achieved?

Comment: is it a single property in the Hash or is only one property in the Hash large.
Depending on how you need to access it you can also compress the whole JSON? or store things in a different way?

Comment: Compressing (and base64 encoding) just one value makes it difficult to work with the JSON, the receiver must now know to unencode and decompress just one value. And it might make everything bigger! I agree with Pascal, compress the whole thing, or reconsider what you're sending. We'd need more context to know what's best, but this smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Base-64 encode](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html) the gzip output, to make it readable characters and therefore valid UTF-8. This will expand the data by about a third more, countering some of your compression. You can also encode with more valid characters, e.g. Base-85, for a little less impact, expanding by about a quarter more in that case. With some work, you should be able to get it down close to a 1/7th increase.

Here is example code in C that encodes bytes to symbols in 1..127, which are all valid UTF-8. (JSON does not permit null bytes in strings.) The resulting expansion is a factor of about 1.145.

```c
#include <stddef.h>

// Encode, reading six or seven bits from bin[0..len-1] to encode each symbol
// to *enc, where a symbol is one byte in the range 1..127. enc must have room
// for at least ceil((len * 4) / 3) symbols. The average number of encoded
// symbols for random input is 1.1454 * len. The number of encoded symbols is
// returned.
size_t enc127(char *enc, unsigned char const *bin, size_t len) {
    unsigned buf = 0;
    int bits = 0;
    size_t i = 0, k = 0;
    for (;;) {
        if (bits < 7) {
            if (i == len)
                break;
            buf = (buf << 8) | bin[i++];
            bits += 8;
        }
        unsigned sym = ((buf >> (bits - 7)) & 0x7f) + 1;
        if (sym > 0x7e) {
            enc[k++] = 0x7f;
            bits -= 6;
        }
        else {
            enc[k++] = sym;
            bits -= 7;
        }
    }
    if (bits)
        enc[k++] = ((buf << (7 - bits)) & 0x7f) + 1;
    return k;
}

// Decode, converting each symbol from enc, which must be in the range 1..127,
// into 6 or 7 bits in the output, from which 8 bits at a time is written to
// bin. bin must have room for at least floor((len * 7) / 8) bytes. The number
// of decoded bytes is returned.
size_t dec127(unsigned char *bin, char const *enc, size_t len) {
    unsigned buf = 0;
    int bits = 0;
    size_t k = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        unsigned sym = enc[i];
        if (sym == 0x7f) {
            buf = (buf << 6) | 0x3f;
            bits += 6;
        }
        else {
            buf = (buf << 7) | (sym - 1);
            bits += 7;
        }
        if (bits >= 8) {
            bin[k++] = buf >> (bits - 8);
            bits -= 8;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that the base64 encoding increases the length of the result, so overall this is only worth it if the compression factor is pretty significant.

Comment: Perfect!  This works.  Thanks!

Comment: You *cannot* mark compressed content as UTF-8. You must treat it as binary until decompressed. Applying Base64 here is a big step backwards. Why not compress the entire JSON document? Most servers do this automatically with *deflate* type modules.

Comment: @tadman I'm not sure why you're saying I cannot.  I did it and it works perfectly.  I tested with lots of inputs and was not able to find one that failed.  I can gzip the content, base64 the result, and then reverse the process and I always get the input back.  The solution here isn't to "mark it as UTF-8".  It's converting it to something that is.  As to why I needed this, that doesn't _really_ matter, IMO.  Yes, the data can be compressed in transit or at rest, but there is code that needs to operate on these hashes that doesn't need the memory overhead of a massive string.

Comment: What I mean is UTF-8 uses an encoding that's in conflict with the output of compression methods like Gzip. You cannot have both valid UTF-8 strings and valid Gzip without additional encoding. I'd argue Bas64 is a huge step backwards here, and that the real solution is compressing the whole document, but it's your call. I'd just encourage you to benchmark on many sample documents how it performs uncompressed, fully compressed, and this weird *partially* compressed form.

Comment: @tadman You can call it weird if you like, but it is quite common to Base-64 or otherwise encode (and somewhat expand) compressed data to restriced character sets, since that is often required for transport.

Comment: @MarkAdler Oh, I know it's *common*, email does it as a matter of habit to shove things into ASCII 7-bit space, but it's not *efficient*.